# Copy file using ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I'm trying to copy from my local machine a file via SSH,
but it doesn't work.

```
devel@siscom-online:~$ scp devel@siscom-online:pgadmin.log /home/user/Downloads/
devel@siscom-online's password:
/home/user/Downloads: No such file or directory
devel@siscom-online:~$
```

Comment: Do you have a user named `user`?

Comment: Use a directory name which exists on your system.  `/home/devel/Downloads` might work.  Your current working directory should work: "`scp devel@siscom-online:pgadmin.log .`" Note the space and then dot at the end of the command.

Comment: we also like text sample, not screen shot who are unsearchable.

Answer (score 3):

The path `/home/user/Downloads/` does not exist on your system or is not accessible. Make sure that the destination directory exits, before starting the copy operation with `scp`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be `scp devel@siscom-online:~/pgadmin.log /home/devel/Downloads/`